# Vue 3 Composition API - Props default and DOM inside lifecycle methods

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3

I have a Vue component inside a NuxtJS app and I'm using the `@nuxtjs/composition-api`.
I have this component which is a `<Link>` component and I would like to make the code clearer.

1. I have a computed property that determines to color of my `UiIcon` from `iconColor, iconColorHover, IconActive`. But most importantly, I want to set it to a specific color if I have a disable class on my root component. It works like that but it doesn't look too good I believe.
2. I found out that `undefined` is the only value that I can use to take `UiIcon` default props if not defined. Empty string like `''` would make more sense to more but it's considered as a valid value. I would have to do some ternary conditions in my `UiIcon` and I'd like to avoid that.

   ```
   <template>
     <div ref="rootRef" class="row">
       <UiIcon
         v-if="linkIcon"
         :type="linkIcon"
         :color="linkIconColor"
         class="icon"
       />
       <a
         class="link"
         :href="linkHref"
         :target="linkTarget"
         :rel="linkTarget === 'blank' ? 'noopener noreferrer' : null"
         @mouseover="linkActive = true"
         @mouseout="linkActive = false"
       >
         <slot></slot>
       </a>
     </div>
   </template>

   <script lang="ts">
    import {
      defineComponent,
      computed,
      ref,
      toRefs,
      nextTick,
      onBeforeMount,
    } from '@nuxtjs/composition-api';
    import { Colors } from '~/helpers/styles';

    export default defineComponent({
     name: 'Link',
     props: {
      href: {
       type: String,
       default: undefined,
      },
      target: {
       type: String as () => '_blank' | '_self' | '_parent' | '_top',
       default: '_self',
      },
      icon: {
       type: String,
       default: undefined,
      },
      iconColor: {
       type: String,
       default: undefined,
      },
      iconHoverColor: {
       type: String,
       default: undefined,
      },
    },
    setup(props) {
      const { href, target, icon, iconColor, iconHoverColor } = toRefs(props);
      const linkActive = ref(false);
      const rootRef = ref<HTMLDivElement | null>(null);

      const writableIconColor = ref('');
      const linkIconColor = computed({
        get: () => {
          const linkDisabled = rootRef.value?.classList.contains('disabled');
          if (linkDisabled) {
            return Colors.DARK_GREY;
          }
          if (linkActive.value && iconHoverColor.value) {
            return iconHoverColor.value;
          }
          return iconColor.value;
        },
        set: (value) => {
          writableIconColor.value = value;
        },
      });

      onBeforeMount(() => {
        nextTick(() => {
          const linkDisabled = rootRef.value?.classList.contains('disabled');
          if (linkDisabled) {
            linkIconColor.value = Colors.DARK_GREY;
          }
        });
      });

      return {
        rootRef,
        linkHref: href,
        linkTarget: target,
        linkIcon: icon,
        linkIconColor,
        linkActive,
      };
     },
    });
   </script>
   ```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Implementing disabled status for a component means it will handle two factors: style (disabled color) and function. Displaying a disabled color is only a matter of style/css. implementing it in programmatical way means it'll take longer time to render completely on user's side and it'll lose more SEO scores. examine `UiIcon`'s DOM from browser and override styles using [Deep selectors](https://vue-loader.vuejs.org/guide/scoped-css.html#deep-selectors).

If I were handling this case, I would have described the color with css and try to minimize programmatic manipulation of style.

```
<template>
  <div :disabled="disabled">
  </div>
</template>
<script>
export default {
  props: {
    disabled: {
      type: Boolean,
      default: false,
    }
  }
}
</script>
// it does not have to be scss.
// just use anything that's
// easier to handle variables.
<style lang="scss">
// I would normally import css with prepend option from webpack,
// but this is just to illustrate the usage.
@import 'custom-styles.scss';

&::v-deep button[disabled] {
  color: $disabled-color;
}
</style>
```

2. attach `validator` function on the props object. [it'll automatically throw errors on exceptions](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-props.html#Prop-Validation).

```js
{
props: {
  icon: {
    type: String,
    default: "default-icon",
    validator(val) {
      return val !== "";
      // or something like, 
      // return val.includes(['iconA', 'iconB'])
    },
  },
}
}
```

Comment: I actually did override the styles via CSS `stroke` attribute before because the icon is an SVG, but I thought it wasn't a good practice to have the color in CSS and JS

Comment: But I ended up doing a lot for just a color haha

Comment: You meant `['iconA', 'iconB'].includes(value)` right ?

Comment: yeah exactly. I wrote the code on the fly, sorry for the mistake.

Comment: it is not necessary to separate colors in js and css. it is possible to use just one .js file to declare colors and utilize it in css via `emotion`.